# Can I Generate GIF FIle From Animated Image in XCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a list of image Frames: img1.png, img2.png,img3.png, img4.png, img5.png.

Can I create gif image from those frames by xcode and save it to my library?

I'm thinking of display them in UIImageView with animationImages, and save this UIImageView to library. But it seems didn't work.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify if you want do this via Xcode the developer IDE or via an iOS Objective-C app created using Xcode.

Comment: I want to create gif from IOS Object-C app (Iphone app)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in Xcode -- if you just want an animation from stills, the easiest thing to do would be to get Quicktime 7 (it's out there somewhere) and do `File -> Open Image Sequence`.  You can use those to open the PNGs as a Quicktime and then save that out.